# Is get() reliable when an auto_ptr is uninitialized?

Tags: c++, c++03, auto-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
std::auto_ptr<std::string> p;

if (p.get() == 0) {
   ...
}
```

Is the `get()` member function a standard and reliable way for checking that `p` has not been initialized? Will it always return 0, irrespective of the platform, compiler, compiler's optimization flags, etc.?

Comment: In this example, `auto_ptr` is *not* "uninitialized". The default constructor initializes the pointer to a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` method of `auto_ptr` has no preconditions.

That means, it is always safe to call that method, regardless of what state the `auto_ptr` object is in.

Contrast this with the `operator*` member function, which does have a precondition of `get() != 0`. The C++ Standard specifies preconditions for member functions in a *Requires* clause. If no such clause is present for a function, it is always safe to call.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such thing as un *uninitialized `std::auto_ptr`*, the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/auto_ptr) initializes the pointer to `0`:

```
explicit auto_ptr( X* p = 0 );
```

Thus `get()` will effectively returns "`0`" on a default constructed `std::auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
std::auto_ptr<std::string> p;
```

calls [the constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/auto_ptr/)

```
explicit auto_ptr (X* p=0) throw();
```

which initializes the internal pointer to 0.

It depends, therefore, what you mean by "has not been initialized". Calling the default ctor, as you showed, will yield a `get` that returns 0. Also initializing it to something else, followed by a call to [`reset(0)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/reset/), will yield a `get` that returns 0.

Comment: When working with multiple platforms, can I rely on the default constructor (without having to check every implementation) or should I explicitly call reset(0) to be sure ?

Comment: No, there is no need to call `reset` explicitly after the default ctor.